# Veronese Embedding for Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question based on following exercise from Bosch's "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" (page 461):

(*) [image]

Let $\mathbb{P}^m$ projective space and $\mathcal{L}:= \mathcal{O}_{P^m}(d)$ an invertible sheaf.

The aim is to construct a map $\varphi:\mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^n$ with $n= \binom{m+d}{m}-1$. It is called also the Veronese embedding.

The construction seems quite straight forward: There exist exactly  $\binom{m+d}{m}$ monomials $s_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m}:=T_0^{k_0}T_1^{k_1}...T_m^{k_m}$ of degree $d$ (so we have $\sum k_i = d$)

and therefore the data $(\mathcal{L}:=\mathcal{O}_{P^m}(d); s_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m})$ determines such $\varphi$ uniquely via

$\mathcal{O}_{P^m}(d)= \varphi^*\mathcal{O}_{P^n}(1)$ and $s_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m}:=f^{\#}(T_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m})$ for $\mathbb{P}^n= Proj(k[T_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m}]_{k_0+k_1,..., k_m=d})$.

My question is how to show that this map "coinsides" with the "common" Veronese embedding in appropriate sense as defined for projective spaces $\mathbb{P}^m_k $ considered as topological spaces here:

(**)
[image]

"In appropriate sense " means namely in following sense:

If we fix a field $K$ (for example $K = \mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}$) then we can consider the set of $K$ valued points $\mathbb{P}^m(K):= Hom_{Sch}(Spec(K), \mathbb{P}^m)$. And it is a fact that $\mathbb{P}^m(K)$ can be endowed with topology making $\mathbb{P}^m(K)$ homeomorphic to the "topological" projective space as defined here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Definition_of_projective_space

Since $\mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^m(K)$ is functorial we obtain from $\varphi$ as defined in (*) a new map $\tilde{\varphi}: \mathbb{P}^m(K) \to \mathbb{P}^n(K)$.

My question is why and how to see that $\tilde{\varphi}$ coinsides exactly with map given here in (**)?

For sake of simplicity assume $K =\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what's confusing you. The definition for schemes is pretty much identical to the definition you gave for topological spaces. Both are defined by the map with homogeneous coordinates being the monomials.

Comment: @jgon: The problem is that $\varphi$ is defined as you mentioned uniquely by the "data" $s_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m}:=T_0^{k_0}T_1^{k_1}...T_m^{k_m}$ with $\sum k_i = d$. So to write $\varphi = (...: T_0^{k_0}T_1^{k_1}...T_m^{k_m} : ...)$ as long as we talk about $\varphi$ as a scheme morphism is only ***symbolically***. It's just a data for $\varphi$. Formally $\varphi$ arrises from glueing restrictions $\varphi_{s_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m}}:X_{s_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m}} \to D_+(T_{k_0,k_1,..., k_m})$ at localisations.

Comment: While the morphism as given in $(**)$ for corresponding  "rough" topological spaces (more precisely $K$-points of $\mathbb{P}^m$) is "concretely" given by $[X_0: X_1:...:X_n] \mapsto [...:X_0^{k_0}X_1^{k_1}...X_m^{k_m} :...]$. Points to Points.

So the core of my question is what concretely does the functor $(-)(K)$ with $\varphi$? So how does it explicitely look like? Yes, intuitively the "shape" of both morphisms from $(*)$ and $(**)$ is identical (nevertheless they are from different categories). What I don't see why $(-)(K)$ "conserves" this shape.